# Is there a way to see every object that references a particular object?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools, firebug

I have a very large and complex javascript program that has a memory leak. I can see what the objects causing it by analyzing the heap, but I can't find all of the references that I need to close off to clean it up. Is there some tool in Firebug or Developer Tool Kit that will let me see all of the objects that are holding a reference to this particular object?